# Laravel why does password go blank with Form helper

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have 3 almost identical form fields. Wondering why the first one goes blank. I am using Laravel 4.2

```
            <div class="col-md-5">
               {{ Form::input('password', 'password', null , array('class' => 'form-control')) }}

               {{ Form::input('text', 'password', null , array('class' => 'form-control')) }}

                <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" id="password" value="{{{Input::old('password', 
                isset($user) ? $user->password : null) }}}" />

            </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laravel's password fields don't have a default value on purpose. This is mostly due security and the user having no idea what's in the field because it's only visible as `***`.

Because of that the syntax for `password()` is actually:

```
public function password($name, $options = array()){
```

So you would use it like this:

```
{{ Form::password('password', array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
```

(Of course `Form::input()` works too but the value will be ignored)

---

The only workaround is to do like you did and use normal HTML:

```
<input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" id="password" value="{{ Input::old('password', '') }}" />
```

**Note** that `$user->password` doesn't make sense (or at least it shouldn't) because you should store the password as hash and not plain text.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. I am okay with $user->password since it is **** anyhow. I want the user to be able to change the password by overwriting the input field. If they leave it untouched it should leave the password unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this

For Password

```
{{ Form::password('password', array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
```

and For Text

```
{{ Form::text('password', null, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
```